# When I mute or unmute in alsamixer, the speaker pop a little bit - by which i think indicates some changes, but I still can't hear anything

Tags: sound, alsa, realtek, audio-jack

I have a PC with realtek audio card attatched . Realtek ALC887-VD 
I've tried to unmute and set all of the audio to make in `alsamixer`, I've tried to reinstall alsamixer `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gnome-alsamixer` and nothing has worked. 
PS: `alsamixer` can detect my audio card (**HDA Intel PCH, Realtek ALC887-VD** and puvacontrol shows only 1 Port: **Digital output (S/PDIF)**. And detected only "**Built-In Audio Digital Stereo (IEC 958)**"
Please help me!
Thank you for your precious time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change profile in PulseAudio app to Analogue Stereo Ouput. That'll do.